# Change/Edit Page Level Permission SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am working on a SharePoint Site 2013, and I have multiple .aspx pages.

Can you please guide me, how can I restrict a specific page to be viewable by few members only.

Answer (score 1):

If its a site page, go to library where it is stored and change item level permission of page, so that it can be viewed by only few members.

If its an application page, in page load event check current logged in user's permission and group and according show him the page or redirect him to access denied page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you don't want them to see but each list object can have it's own permissions so you can stop inheritance on a specific List.. remove everyone leaving only the site owner, and the group you want to have access.

The Page will should.. but it won't show any contents.